# ANGULAR 2/4 : call function for each row in NgFor

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

i'm learning AngularJS, and i need some help.

I have a template like this

```
    <div *ngFor="let beat of data" (invoke)="myFunction(beat.id)" class="item">
      <div class="item-column-1 inline">
        <div class="item-column-1-container">
          <img class="item-img1" src="/CMP.jpg">
          <p>{{beat.uploader}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-column-2 inline">
        <span class="item-title">{{beat.title}}</span>
        <p class="item-score">245 </p>
        <span>#TRAPCHILL</span>
        <p>#TYGA #DRAKE #YOUNG THUG #MIGOS</p>
        <P>Posted: 2 days ago</P>
          <!-- <input (click)="rate(beat.id,1)" alt="beat.id" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="{{beat.id}}">1</label>
          <input (click)="rate(beat.id,2)" alt="beat.id" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="{{beat.id}}">2</label>
          <input (click)="rate(beat.id,3)" alt="beat.id" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="{{beat.id}}">3</label> -->
          <div  (click)="rate(beat.id,1)" class="flamme"></div>
          <div  (click)="rate(beat.id,2)" class="flamme"></div>
          <div  (click)="rate(beat.id,3)" class="flamme"></div>

        <span></span>
      </div>
      <button (click)="play(beat.path)" type="button" name="button">play</button>
      <button (click)="sendMsg()">Send</button>


      <div class="item-column-3 inline">
          <img class="album-cover" src="{{beat.path_img}}" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>
```

> Now, for each data in my ngFor, i want to call a function ( in
>   occurence myFunction(beat.id)), this function will return a number.
>
> i wanna  retrieve the number of the return function, for display it in
>   each data of my ngFor...
>
> I've tried to create a directive "invoke", with an output event, and
>   then in my ngAfterContentInit(), i emitted my output, but nothing
>   happened, it's not trigged when my data is loaded.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[invoke]'})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
retrievedObject : any;
src : string;
data : any;
current:any;
rating : any;
countRate : any;
subscription: Subscription;

duration:any;
@Output() invoke:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
---
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.invoke.emit(null);
}

myFunction(beat_id){

alert('trigged');
}
```

So if anybody have a solution.. thank's !

Comment: That's a very bad idea. Can you please elaborate what you need this for?
Every time Angular runs change detection, this function will be called. This will drag down performance of your page dramatically.

Comment: "i wanna retrieve the number of the return function, for display it in each data of my ngFor..." for this either create a pipe, or pre-calculate the value for each item of the array in code and add it to the array or create a new array where the values match the index of the original array they are associated with. You can then use the `...;let i=index"` of `*ngFor` to access the value of the 2nd array with the same index of the array `*ngFor` is iterating over.

Comment: @Brayan you're not learning AngularJS (aka Angular 1), you're learning Angular (aka Angular 2/4). It's confusing, I know.

Comment: Brayan233, why don't you loop through the items in the constructor and do the calculations there. You can append the value of the calculation to the object at each iteration. Then it will become available in the ngFor in the object itself.

Comment: My need is : I have some data display with NgFor, for each data, i wan't to call a function with param ( somevalue of the ngFor), and then display the return value of the function for each my data. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Thanks for the pipe solution, i'll take a look, it's sounds like a nice way for my need ! @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: As I mentioned above, either create a pipe to do the calculation and returning the value, or pre-calculate in code, store the returned values in an array and reference these values in bindings, instead of calling methods. Calling methods in bindings to get values is usually a very bad thing in Angular 2+

Comment: Nice idea,i had no thought about that, i'll try it, and keep you informed @user3492940
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.data = dataFromSomewhere();
this.dataOpt = this.data.map((d) => this.myFunction(d.id));
```

```
<div *ngFor="let beat of data; let i=index"  class="item">
  <div>{{dataOpt[i]}}</div>
```

The pipe variant:

```
@Pipe({selector: myFunc})
class MyPipy implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val:string) {
    return // do the same calculation here that you would do in `myFunction`;
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
<div *ngFor="let beat of data; let i=index"  class="item">
  <div>{{data | myPipe}}</div>
```

(the pipe needs to be registered in declarations of the module (or in an imported module)

Comment: Better that my deleted answer :)

Comment: It's a little chinese for me , i'll try to implement your solution in my code, and  I will keep you informed, Thanks  ! :)

Comment: Hello @Günter Zöchbauer, thank's for your answer, i've implement your first solution and it work pretty well, .map() is really powerfull.
But i've a little problem, the value i want return is in a subcribe function like this :
   this.beatService.getRating(beat_id).subscribe( response => {  this.countRate = response.results[0].total_rate });

And when i want return this.countRate, it's undefined outside the subcribe function... What should i do ?

Comment: That's normal behavior and very frequently asked question from people starting with observables. Just move all the vode inside `subscribe(...)`. What you pass to `subscribe(...)` is a function that will be called by the observable when a value becomes available. That's usually much later than when the code after `subscribe()` is executed.

Comment: Ohhh sure, ok i understand.
So now everything is working, so i have :

this.dataOpt = this.data.map((d) => this.getRating(d.id));
getRating(beat_id){

   this.beatService.getRating(beat_id).subscribe( response => {  this.setCountRating(response) });

}

setCountRating(data){

  let total_rate = data.results[0].total_rate;
  this.countRate.push(total_rate);

}

Do you think its a good practice or u have better practice for this ? Thank's very much again.

Comment: There might be something better, but I don't know observables well enough myself. I'm developing in Dart and know TS only from answering SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

Get an array as property on your class. Each time your function is called, set the corresponding item (say i) of this array to the value. And in the template reference the i item of that same array.