# Why *ngFor repeat more than element in an array

Tags: angular, ngfor

Why ***ngFor** repeat for **(array count) x 4** times ?

I have created simple Angular2 project using Angular-cli. I am using Angular4.

**AppComponent (app.component.ts)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    protected square(v) {
        const retVal = v * v;
        console.log(retVal, new Date().getMilliseconds());
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let v of values">
    <span>{{square(v)}}</span>
</div>
```

**Result (rendered HTML)**

[image]

**Question ??**

In HTML it is producing only **5 elements** but when you look at console it is printing **20 times**.

What I believe it should be only call **square(v)** for **5** times only not **20** times.

Comment: That is expected and has to do with change detection and how *ngFor does rendering. You should not use non idempotent computed values in your loop, rather a static list that only changes when your code decides it has to change (ie. like an add new click or remove click  or edit click etc).

Comment: but this is causing big issue for me when i have components within components within components ... it is repeating for indefinite time ... is there any way to stop it once all elements rendered ?

Comment: Are you rendering dynamic components inside the `*ngFor`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880950/angular-2-4-call-function-for-each-row-in-ngfor/45881293#45881293

Comment: yes I am using dynamic components

Comment: See [Dynamically adding components in ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274281), there are also some additional related [so] question/answers in the comments of this linked question.

Comment: Awesome guys .. thanks ... This issue was driving me crazy ...